# jquery replace an ID with variable

Tags: jquery, html, variables

I have an id="test" and would like to have it replaced by the variable:PitchesRemaining:
http://jsfiddle.net/xtian/G7Qdp/

HTML:

```
    <div class="wrap wrap-widgets relative">
        <div class="speedometer" id="test">6</div>
        <span id="AveragePitches">55</span>
        <span id="PitchesToday">15</span>
    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
        $(function(){
        var AveragePitches = parseInt($("#AveragePitches").text());
        var Buffer = AveragePitches * .2;
        var PitchesMax = AveragePitches + Buffer;
        var PitchesToday = parseInt($("#PitchesToday").text());
        var PitchesRemaining = PitchesMax - PitchesToday;

        $("#test").change(function() {
            PitchesRemaining = $(this).val();
            }).change();
    });
```

Comment: "The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements."  http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: you would like the id to be replaced to `id="x"`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Do you want to change the ID or the contents of the div?

Comment: I want the value of #test to change to the value of var PitchesRemaining

Comment: Also, `<div>` tags don't have `value` attributes, so `.val()` won't work.  You need to use `.html()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just change the Id using jQuery's [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
obj.attr("id", PitchesRemaining);
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do though. If you're trying to use the ID to track a variable, then perhaps you should take a look at [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) instead.

**EDIT:**

After reading your comment in the question; to change the text of the div to the value of `PitchesRemaining`, just use [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$("#test").text(PitchesRemaining);
```

Or [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$("#test").html(PitchesRemaining);
```

Comment: that could messup his change event wouldnt it ? e.g. if he changed for a second time i would of thought it wouldnt work

Comment: @Val - Works fine. jQuery hooks up the DOM events of an object, not a particular id: http://jsfiddle.net/3umZ9/. Although, it's not what the OP was after anyway, so I've updated the answer.

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing btw just thought of it logically but that is good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

To change the value of a `<div>` do this:

```
$('#test').html(PitchesRemaining);
```

Note: `.change()` events are only for input elements, not for divs.